# Using target="_blank" in PHP

Tags: php, html, target

I've searched for a couple hours now and I can't seem to figure out how to include the target="_blank" attribute into the 'href' => section of this php without breaking it.

here's the code:

```
'chat' => array(
            'title' => 'Chat',
            'href' => 'http://mywebsite.com/',
            'show' => true,
            'sub_buttons' => array(
            ),
        ),
```

Is it possible to use that target attribute in this code?

This is from the Subs.php file used in SMF forums.

Comment: Who knows, what turns that code into `<a href="">...`? Try it..? Impossible to tell given the current information in the question.

Comment: target is an attribute, like href.  but your code offers no way of seeing how the html is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try appending `" target="_blank` to the `href` value, but if that works, you have a serious issue on your hand (the value should be escaped).

In this situation, it would be better to extend whatever method turns this array into HTML, so `target` is also an acceptable attribute.

Comment: Oh ok, that's what I was missing. The function that turned href into HTML. I didn't realize that existed.

Comment: Would it be easier to just use a basic text link?

Comment: @SharkBite, that really depends on how easy it is to extend the function that generated the HTML, how well you know PHP, if you can even access a place to insert vanilla HTML, etc. Personally, I'd suggest sticking with the code that's already in place and extending the function (then you can reuse it later).

Answer (score 0):

Yes @sachleen is correct. You have just provided an array. There will be some function/method its creating the url. Either add an extra options array which has the attributes and build it like that.

Example I am copying from Aura.View helper

https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.View#using-helpers

`$this->anchor($href, $text)` returns an `<a href="$href">$text</a>` tag

This is achieved with the help of the code

```
class Anchor extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($href, $text, $attribs = [])
    {
        // build text and return
        if ($attribs) {
            $skip = ['href'];
            $attr = $this->attribs($attribs, $skip);
            return "<a href=\"$href\" $attr>$text</a>";
        } else {
            return "<a href=\"$href\">$text</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.View/blob/master/src/Aura/View/Helper/Anchor.php

Hope that helps.